# How do you place waypoints on your map in MInecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I have created a map in my Minecraft world (on my Ipad). But I just wanted to add waypoints to you know, signify where things are. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1):

On Minecraft Java Edition, if you right-click a banner with your map, the banner will show up on the map, but because you're on Minecraft Bedrock Edition, you'll have to use a slightly more difficult way. In my past survival worlds, I have taken concrete of different colours, and laid them out in a large square, so that it shows up on the map. If you don't want a large area of concrete right next to your locations, you can just lock your map by putting it in a cartography table with a glass pane, and destroy the concrete afterwards. The square will stay on the map.

Note: You can use any block you want, I just like using concrete blocks.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll try it out.

Comment: This is a pretty good idea, especially the locking the map then destroying it part! I don't think there's a better way than this, note that you will need a bigger shape the more zoomed out the map is